# Save OpenHTMLtoPDF Content to PDF file

Tags: c#, openhtmltopdf

I have this PDF file that I have generated with `OpenHTMLtoPDF`.

```
string html = "<html><body><h1>TEST</h1></body></html>";
var pdf = Pdf.From(html).OfSize(size);
byte[] content = pdf.Content();
```

However, I cannot figure out how to save it to the disk. There appears to not be a method to save to the hard drive.

Comment: I posted this as a Q&A style question as I got stuck on this for a few hours, and was unable to find anything on how to do this. Once I realized that the return value of `pdf.Content()` was a byte array I was able to figure this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very easy since `pdf.content()` is passing you an array of bytes you can simply call `File.WriteAllBytes()` to save the file to the hard drive.

```C#
using OpenHtmlToPdf;
using System.IO;
namespace Test{
    class TestOpenHTMLtoPDF{
         private void Main(){
             string html = "<html><body><h1>TEST</h1></body></html>";
             var pdf = Pdf.From(html).OfSize(size);
             byte[] content = pdf.Content();
             File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Test.pdf", content);
         }
    }
}
```